# Return nested Promise.all result in firebase function onCall

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions, es6-promise

I'm creating a cloud function that receives a call from the client including the current user id. What I'm trying to achieve is get a list of friend ids from the "users" collection under the current user id and then for each friend id get a list of objects from a collection named "locations". The code below has the correct queries but there is some confusion around the promise handling and the return statements. How can I correctly return the result from inside the second 'then' ? Currently returning HttpsCallableResult with data as an empty map even thought it should include 2 objects.

```
exports.friendsData = functions.https.onCall((data, context) => {
    return admin
        .firestore()
        .collection('users')
        .doc(data.id)
        .get()
        .then(snapshot => {
            const friendsIds = snapshot.data().friends;
            console.log('friendsIds', friendsIds);

            return Promise.all(
                friendsIds.map(id => {
                    console.log('id', id);
                    return admin
                        .firestore()
                        .collection('locations')
                        .where('userid', '==', id)
                        .get();
                })
            );
        })
        .then(locationSnapshots => {
            const results = [];
            for (const locationSnap of locationSnapshots) {
                const data = locationSnap.data();
                console.log('data', data);

                results.push(data);
            }
            console.log('resuts', resuts);
            return resuts;
        })
        .catch(reason => {
            return reason;
        });
});
```

EDIT 
locations collection has documents with the autogenerated ids and each document has field named "userid" which is used for the where query
[Image for location collection structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BrIt6.png)

Updated code based on comments. locationSnapshots should be an array of query snapshots for each promise added before. Still getting undefined.

Comment: `return results` looks correct to me for that `.then()` handler.  Is `admin.firestore().collection().where()` a promise or do you need something else there to get the promise?  On another topic, your `.catch()` is "eating" the error and returning reason as a resolved value, rather than allowing the returned promise to stay rejected.  Do `throw reason` or just remove that `.catch()` entirely if you want to propagate errors correctly.

Comment: @StackSlave - That's not correct.  The return value from a `.then()` handler becomes the resolved value of that `.then()`'s promise.  That return value is critically important in promise code.

Comment: Does `locationSnapshots` contain the right data?  If you `console.log(results)` right before you return it, does it contain the right data?

Comment: @jfriend00 I fixed the "where" query which was wrong and was missing .get(). However, still the same result. locationSnapshots.docs returns undefined.

Comment: Well, where does it go wrong.  You need to track the data at each point and tell us where it goes wrong for you?

Comment: @jfriend00 I certainly get the ids used for the where query, but get undefined for its result. Which means the where query is still wrong.. I added an image for the structure of the 'locations' collection.

Comment: I see one thing that looks wrong.  Change this `for (const id in friendsIds) ` to this `for (const id of friendsIds) `.  If `friendsIds` is an array, yu were just getting the array indexes instead of the actual values.

Answer (score 0):

I'll document the things wrong we've discovered so far in an answer:

First, you need a `.get()` after the `.where(...)` to get the promise.

Second, if `friendsIds` is an array and you're trying to iterate the contents of the array, change this:

```
for (const id in friendsIds)
```

to this:

```
for (const id of friendsIds)
```

When you use `in`, it iterates properties of the object which in the case of an array would be the array indexes, not the array values.

Even better would be switch to use `.map()` since you're trying to create an array from an array.  Change this:

```
        const promises = [];
        for (const id in friendsIds) {
            const p = admin
                .firestore()
                .collection('locations')
                .where('userid', '==', id)
                .get();
            promises.push(p);
        }

        return Promise.all(promises);
```

to this:

```
        return Promise.all(friendsIds.map(id => {
            return admin
                .firestore()
                .collection('locations')
                .where('userid', '==', id)
                .get();
        }));
```